# How to remember which page the user was on before logout?

Tags: users, redirect

I want to make a website with restricted user access. I have found several plugins to do that. Now I want my wordpress website to remember the page the user was on before they logout. Besides that, I want my site to redirect the user, after login, to the page they were on before logout.

How can I do that? I couldn't find anything on the internet.

Comment: If this is a cookie based solution, you would simply need to create and update a cookie on each page load - then when the user returns, check if there is a cookie and filter the redirect after login to go to the value stored in the cookie.

Comment: Welcome to WordPress Stack Exchange! Asking for plugins is something we don't allow, because it leads to spam and dead URLs over time. However, what you are asking for is rather easy to implement, and asking for the code solution is fine. So I took the liberty to rewrite your question a bit in order to keep it on topic.